# Ionic/Angular app not getting data from MongoDb database

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, ionic-framework, mean-stack

I'm creating a budget app that should be retrieving expenses from a MongoDB database collection and displaying them once the app starts.

I set up the routing to/from MongoDB and tested the API with SOAP and the get response works properly.

[SOAP GET request test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2dqZ.png)

Here is my code for that part:

**app.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': true}));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../www')));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../www')));

const conn = 
  'mongoDbDatabaseLink';

// put API require statements here
const ExpenseApi = require('./routes/expense-api');

// database connection
mongoose.connect(conn, {
  // promiseLibrary: require('bluebird'),
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
}).then(() => {
  console.debug('Connection to the database instance was successful');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(`MongoDB Error: ${err.message}`);
});

// API connections here
app.use('/api/expenses', ExpenseApi);


// create and start server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // server port
http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Application started and listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

**expense-api.js**

```js
const express = require('express');

const Expense = require('../models/expense-model');
const BaseResponse = require('../services/base-response');
const ErrorResponse = require('../services/error-response');

const router = express.Router();

  router.get ('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      Expense.find({isDisabled: false},
       (err, expenses) => {
         
        //Error response
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            const findAllExpensesMongodbErrorResponse = new ErrorResponse ('500', 'Internal Server Error', err);
            res.status(500).send(findAllExpensesMongodbErrorResponse.toObject());
            // Success Response
          }else{
            console.log(expenses);
            const findAllExpensesSuccessResponse = new BaseResponse ('200', 'Request Successful', expenses);
            res.json(findAllExpensesSuccessResponse.toObject());
          }
        });

        //catch error response
      }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        const findAllExpensesCatchErrorResponse = new ErrorResponse ('500', 'Internal Server Error', e.message);
        res.status(500).send(findAllExpensesCatchErrorResponse.toObject());
      }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

**expense-model.js**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let expenseSchema = new Schema({
  isDisabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  name: { type: String },
  dueDate: { type: String },
  amount: { type: String }
}, {collection: "expenses"});


module.exports = mongoose.model("Expense", expenseSchema);
```

---

Then I tried to incorporate it in the app that I am working on. When I serve the app and run the server, it loads the app but I get a 404 error when it tries the GET request:

[GET request fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOG7c.png)

Here is my code for that:

**expense-budget.page.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ExpensesService } from 'src/app/services/expense.service';
import { ExpenseInterface } from 'src/app/interfaces/expense-interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-expense-budget',
  templateUrl: './expense-budget.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./expense-budget.page.scss'],
})
export class ExpenseBudgetPage implements OnInit {
  expenses: ExpenseInterface[];

  constructor(
    private expensesService: ExpensesService
    ) {
      this.expensesService.findAllExpenses().subscribe(res => {
        this.expenses = res ['data'];
        console.log(this.expenses);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

**expense.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ExpensesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  findAllExpenses(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('/api/expenses');
  }
}
```

---

I basically copied this code from another project I made and it still works fine. I'm not sure if it has something to do with me using the Ionic framework on this project or not.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Based on the first image (SOAP), the request Url points to **http://localhost:3000/**, while second image, the request Url points to **http://localhost:4200/**. With `/api/expenses` without specific the full request Url, it will refer to http://localhost:4200/ as your Angular App. You should specify the full request Path and also take concern on [CORS](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/do-you-know-how-to-resolve-cors-issues-in-angular-9d818474825f) as well.

Comment: Thanks! I missed the URL difference and when I go to localhost:3000, it pulls the Array of data from the database. I am still kind of knew to all this so I need to learn about CORS and stuff as well. Thanks again.